# FormRequest all() method causes Reflection exception in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

**Issue with laravel 5.5**

If I use the `all()` method in formRequest class, It throws *reflection exception*

```
ReflectionException
Class App\Http\Requests\CashDepositRequest does not exist
```

but when I remove the `all()` method, it works well.

This was not an issue in laravel 5.4

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class CashDepositRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'amount' => 'bail|required|numeric',
            'gateway' => 'bail|required|exists:gateways,id',
        ];
    }
    //This method causes reflection exception
    public function all()
    {
        $this->attributes = parent::all();
        $this->attributes['amount'] = $this->attributes['amount'];
        return $this->attributes;
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to modify user input in the formRequest class in laravel 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

First of all `all()` is not property but class method.

Second thing is the signature of this method. Signature in parent class looks like this:

```
public function all($keys = null)
```

so you should update it in child class to the same.

If you upgraded from previous releases in [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/upgrade) you can read:

> If you are overriding the all method of the Illuminate\Http\Request class, you should update your method signature to reflect the new $keys argument:

and this is probably what causes the problem in your case.